# Format money value into pounds and pence

Tags: javascript

I have helper function formatting my money value into pounds and pence:

```
formatMoney: function(10496.470000000001){
    return value.toString().replace(/(\d)(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, "1,");
},
```

Gives me:

`11,496.471,001,001,001`

Is there a way I can format this accurately into pounds and pence? so it reads, `£11,496.471p`

Comment: So whats the "001,001,001"? What value goes in?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/149055/how-can-i-format-numbers-as-money-in-javascript

Comment: You need to add `.toFixed(2)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In addition to the toFixed method call mentioned previously, the second parameter to replace should be "$1," rather than "1,". Also, your conversion to a number is somewhat fragile. Here's my attempt at remedying these issues:

```js
function convert(value){
    return "£"+((Number(value)||0).toFixed(2).replace(/(\d)(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, "$1,"))+"p";
}

console.log(convert(10496.470000000001));
```

Answer (score -1):

The Regexp doesn't care about the decimals you pass in. You need to convert your input to already have 2 decimals:

```
return value.toFixed(2).replace(/(\d)(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, "1,");
             ^^^^^^^^^^
```

```js
function convert(value){
    return value.toFixed(2).replace(/(\d)(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, "1,");
}

console.log(convert(10496.470000000001));
```

Comment: Why does `10496.470000000001` format to `11,496.47`?  PS. I didn't downvote.

Comment: Thats what you wanted right? Or does it need the extra `1`?

Comment: I am not the OP but I suspect the OP has an error in their script too.  Unless I missed something and they do want to add a thousand as well as format to currency display.